# How to parse /proc/meminfo

Tags: c, parsing

I had been using `scanf` to pull 3 values out of /proc/meminfo like so:

```
 fscanf (info, "MemTotal: %*d kB MemFree: %d kB Buffers: %d kB Cached: %d kB", &memfree, &membuffers, &memcache);
```

The problem is that at some point they added a new field ( MemAvailable ) and that breaks this parsing.  How can I parse this file while tolerating the addition of new fields in the future?

Answer (score 3):

Look how `top` does it: http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/procps/procps/proc/sysinfo.c?revision=1.40&view=markup

The function `void meminfo(void)` begins at line 544.